Backpropagation - The neural network doesn't get trained properly?
I have this code:
import numpy as np 

class neural_network:
    def __init__(self, layers, alpha = 0.01):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.activate = (lambda x: 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x)))
        self.rate = (lambda x: x * (1.0 - x))
        self.W = list()
        for i in np.arange(0, len(layers) - 2):
            self.W.append(np.random.randn(layers[i] + 1, layers[i + 1] + 1))
        i += 1 
        self.W.append(np.random.randn(layers[i] + 1, layers[i + 1]))

    def forward(self, I):
        I = np.atleast_2d(I)
        I = np.c_[I, np.ones(I.shape[0])]
        z = np.matmul(I, self.W[0])
        a = self.activate(z)
        self.A = [a]
        for i in np.arange(0, len(self.W)):
            z = np.matmul(self.A[-1], self.W[i])
            a = self.activate(z)
            self.A.append(a)
        return a

    def error(self, O, Y):
        return (1 / 2) * np.mean((O - Y) ** 2)

    def backward(self, I, Y):
        O = self.forward(I)
        error = O - Y
        D = [self.rate(self.A[-1]) * error]
        for i in np.arange(len(self.W) - 1, 0, -1):
            d = np.matmul(D[-1], self.W[i].T) * self.rate(self.A[i])
            D.append(d)
        D = D[::-1]
        for i in np.arange(0, len(self.W)):
            self.W[i] -= np.matmul(self.A[i].T, D[i]) * self.alpha
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nn = neural_network([2, 2, 1])
    I = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
    Y = np.array([[1], [1], [1], [0]])
    O = nn.forward(I)
    print(nn.error(O, Y))
    for i in range(10000):
        nn.backward(I, Y)
    O = nn.forward(I)
    print(O)
    print(nn.error(O, Y))
    exit(0)

My last post got deleted for lack of clarity, so I will try to be as clear as I can:
The network doesn't get trained
There are no error messages, it is a logical error that I can't find, I don't know where it is, I just know it is in somewhere in that short code
The network is suppose to learn the XOR table of truth, but seems to normalize the output in a way that all of the outputs are more or less the same (it doesn't get trained properly.)
I don't know what else to say. I was asked for error messages but like I said the error is in the result of the algorithm.
Thanks beforehand for any suggestion.
P.S. If anyone knows any forum that is more AI-specific, please also let me know, I would appreciate it. Maybe this is not exactly the right place for this kind of question.
I tried to implement the backpropagation algorithm and I was expecting the neural network to get trained properly.
Edit: A very important thing to take into account is that I followed this guide to try to make it work: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html
Edit 2: What I'm looking for is something like: "In this line, you are trying to multiply this with this other thing but actually you can't do it with a transposed matrix." This is just an example. And yes, I gave a mathematical example, but I want a programming answer, because I'm programming a neural network, that is the purpose of the question (In case it seems off-topic.)

I'm not super familiar with the subject matter, but it's not clear to me how your code properly implements backpropagation. The state of the system, like the weights, doesn't seem to change meaningfully each loop (as in the weights/biases for the gradient descent). Note use of backprop in the article. In your code, I'm not sure how you're expecting this to work. Maybe there's some confusion about variable scoping and reassignment works in Python? Try logging your state changes and make sure that things are changing each loop how you expect. Then maybe a more well-defined problem will emerge.

@sytech Well, logging may help. I tried that a couple of times and maybe insisting on it a little more would help, but I still want a clarification of what is wrong in that code so I can go on because to me, taking into account the way backpropagation works, it looks perfect (but it's not.) Thank you for the suggestion
